# if statement\how to loop problems

Tags: python

Okay so when i run this code and put in 50 for example it will list all the grades under that. How do i fix this? Also how can i make this more efficient? this is quite a lot of code for quite a simple task put i'm not sure how to achieve it. thanks for all replies.

```
print("-------WELCOME-------")
testscore = int(input("What mark did you get?"))
if testscore>= 80:
    print("You got an A!!")
else:
    if testscore>= 70:
        print("You got an B!")
    if testscore>= 60:
        print("You got an C.")
    if testscore>= 50:
        print("You got an D.")
    if testscore>= 40:
        print("You got an F.")
    if testscore>= 30:
        print("You got a G. Wow.")
    if testscore<= 20:
        print("There is nothing this low. Maybe you should have studied more? re-think your life please.")

second = input("do you want to get another test score?")
if second == "yes":
    testscore = int(input("What mark did you get?"))

if testscore>= 80:
    print("You got an A!!")
else:
    if testscore<= 70:
        print("You got an B!")
    if testscore<= 60:
        print("You got an C.")
    if testscore<= 50:
        print("You got an D.")
    if testscore<= 40:
        print("You got an F.")
    if testscore<= 30:
        print("You got a G. Wow.")
    if testscore<= 20:
        print("There is nothing this low. Maybe you should have studied more? re-think your life please.")
if second == "no":
    print("Thanks for using MARK TO GRADE CONVERTER. See you soon!")
```

Comment: Use `elif` instead of `if` for all but the first condition.

Comment: Try logically reasoning through the code.  What happens when you input 73?  It's less than 80, so it will go into the else statement.  Track through each and every step and you'll see why @tobias_k is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that all those conditions in the `else` part are tested independently.

```
if testscore>= 80:
    print("You got an A!!")
else:
    if testscore>= 70:
        print("You got an B!")
    if testscore>= 60:
        print("You got an C.")
    if ...
```

If `testscore` is `75`, then the first condition is true, so `print("You got an B!")` is executed. It then tests the second condition, which is also true, so it executes `print("You got an C!")`, and so on. For the first two conditions (A and B) you used `else: if ...`, which went in the right direction, but using `else: if` for all would result in a huge cascade of nested blocks. Instead, you can use `elif` for all but the first condition. This way, the next condition is only tested if the previous one evaluated to false:

```
if testscore>= 80:
    print("You got an A!!")
elif testscore>= 70:
    print("You got an B!")
elif testscore>= 60:
    print("You got an C.")
elif ...
```

And similar for the second block of `if` statements further down. (The comparison is reversed in that block, but actually I'd guess that those blocks should be the same; in this case, you should make that a function and call the function twice instead of replicating that code.)

---

Alternatively, you could e.g. create a list of grades and scores and then find the `next` score that satisfies the condition in a single line:

```
>>> grades = (('A', 80), ('B', 70), ('C', 60), ('D', 50), ('F', 0))
>>> score = 56
>>> next((g for g, n in grades if score >= n))
'D'
```

Comment: Thanks i tried that and it now it works perfectly. Do you have any idea how  i can do this more efficiently? like a loop or something? I'm not sure if that's right or if you can even use that but i'm abit of a noob :/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reduce the code and make it more efficient you can use a `dictionary` to store the grades and use integer divison on the grade to get the key, as the following:

```
    grades = {7:'B', 6:'C', 5:'D', 4:'F', 3:'G'}               
    testscore = int(input("What mark did you get?"))
    if testscore>= 80:
        print("You got an A!!")
    elif testscore < 30:
        print("There is nothing this low. Maybe you should have studied more? re-think your life please.")
    else:
        print("You got an " + grades[testscore // 10] + "!")
```

and if you want to `loop` you can use:

```
    loop = 'yes'
    while loop == 'yes':
        #code here
        loop = raw_input('Do you want to get another test score?')
```

Comment: Thanks alot for helping me out